# Regular expression to allow only one special character Middle on the string

Tags: regex

Need a regex to match below text

```
testword
testWord
TestA/Test
testt test
TestA-Test
```

I want to check whether in a given string two texts  are joined with a space dash or slash
string should start with a test and end with a text
These are the possible word

```
"wordOne/wordTwo"
"wordOne-wordTwo"
"wordOne wordTwo"
"wordOne"
```

Tried with this. didn't work

```
^[a-zA-Z][/- ]?[a-zA-Z]
```

Comment: Either `[-\/ ]` (dash goes first) or `[\/\- ]` (dash escaped). Plus you need multipliers after letter definitions.  Slash needs escaping as well.

Comment: Also please be clear about *"...middle on the string."*. Do you actuall mean that letters at either side need to be balanced? In that case the sample data shouldn't match.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/p0rKZs/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit hard to understand what you are looking for but it looks like what you want is something more like `^[a-zA-Z]+[\/\- ]?[a-zA-Z]+`

You are missing is `+` after the `[a-zA-Z]` to indicate there is one or more, and then you need `\` infront of `-` and `/` to escape

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to allow a single letter as a word:

```
^[a-zA-Z]+(?:[\/ -][a-zA-Z]+)?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[a-zA-Z]+`
- `(?:[\/ -][a-zA-Z]+)?` Optionally match either `/`   `-` and 1+ chars a-zA-Z
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tbV8ox/1)